# Java synchronization task

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task to write simple booking system, I have done it except one thing, the last task I could not understand  it properly, can you please give me how I can approach this last problem because I dont know even how to form a question about it and search in google:

> - Try to redesign your application so that it is still thread-safe, but without using locking mechanisms (i.e. without synchronization or
>     java.util.concurrent.locks)

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
public class Bus{

    private final boolean [] seats = new boolean[50];
    private int nextSeat = 0;

    public void bookSeat() throws Exception{
        if(nextSeat<seats.length){
        seats[nextSeat]=true;
        nextSeat++;
        System.out.print("Seat number " +nextSeat+ " booked");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The bus is full sorry");
        }
        }

}

public class Passenger extends Thread{

    Bus bus;
    String passengerName;

    public Passenger(Bus bus, String passengerName){
        this.bus=bus;
        this.passengerName=passengerName;
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized(bus){
            try {
                bus.bookSeat();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Passenger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("by " + passengerName);

        }
    }

    public String getPassengerName() {
        return passengerName;
    }

    public void setPassengerName(String passengerName) {
        this.passengerName = passengerName;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Bus someCompany = new Bus();

        Passenger p1 = new Passenger(someCompany,"Name1");
        Passenger p2 = new Passenger(someCompany, "Name2");

        p1.start();
        p2.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: try simply removing that synchronized statement from your code; and run it a few times. You will figure that you get different results all the time - because as soon as more than one thread is manipulating data that calls for trouble. Your assignment is then figure ways to avoid that problems (without using synchronized, but other means).

Comment: Lock-free synchronization such as `AtomicBoolean` etc. may be what they were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to use classes from the package `java.util.concurrent.atomic`, indeed they allow you to make your class thread safe without paying the price of a lock since they propose a lock free approach.

Here is how I would modify your code to make it thread safe without using **intrinsic** or **explicit** locks:

```
public class Bus {

    private final AtomicIntegerArray seats = new AtomicIntegerArray(50);
    private final AtomicInteger nextSeat = new AtomicInteger();

    public void bookSeat() throws Exception {
        // get the next value, then increment the sequence
        int next = nextSeat.getAndIncrement();
        // check if we don't exceed the size of the array 
        if (next < seats.length()){
            // Set the value at the index "next" to "1" for booked
            seats.set(next, 1);
            System.out.println("Seat number " +next+ " booked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The bus is full sorry");
        }
    }
}
```

**NB:** I use an `AtomicIntegerArray` as there is no equivalent for `boolean` and we
need an array with `volatile` values so simply `0` is `false` and `1` is `true`.